# Modal popup changing gridview row colors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2015

My `webform` has a regular `gridview`. I bind it to a datatable and then change `cell.BackCOlor` in `RowDataBound`. I'm including the code even though I don't think it's related to the issue:

```
protected void GridViewButtons_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(cell.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything's working well with the gridview. On the webform there's also a button to the far left that simply displays a modalpopup. This is the code:

```
protected void ButtonDisplayPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

The issue is that when the modal popup is displayed, the color of some of the rows disappear. You can see it in the printscreen:
[image]

What can the problem be?

In this webform I also had a Timer enabled that binds the gridview every 5 seconds. This Timer is disabled at the moment to make sure it's not causing the issue. The reason I mention it is that, with the Timer enabled, the gridview would rebind (with the Modal panel still displayed) and that *refresh* would paint those rows correctly, and problem solved.

But it seems that something happens with the gridview colors when the modal panel is displayed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because the modal popup is affecting the background. Add a CSS class to your popup:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
```

Then adjust the CSS below until you get the desired result you want.:

```
.modalBackground 
{
    background-color:#EBEBEB;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

Comment: I already have that CSS class.  The only difference is the `background-color`, but the rest of the properties are the same.

Comment: I added your CSS class and I still get the same issue.

Comment: I asked that you tweak the CSS I gave you or the one one you have until you get the desired result. It wasn't supposed to be copy pasted. Honestly, you should not even worry about it because this is what modal does:it dims the background so the modal becomes the main focus. When you close the modal, it will go back to the original color. If you want you can remove the CSS body I gave you and the one you have and see if that is what you prefer.

Comment: I understand that, but I thought your solution was based on a similar issue you were having.  This CSS class is needed for any modal popup.

Comment: Yes it's needed but you can adjust it and even remove some of the items from the body. Please note I did not say to remove the class but to make the body empty or to tweak it.

Comment: The issue is not with the modal popup. I eliminated the modal popup and added a button. The button doesn't do anything, just does regular postback when I click on it.

Comment: The problem is that the backcolor of the rows that have this issue are in hex (ie. #FB7703). Apparently, it doesn't paint it fast enough, or something similar.